# Rails model design: propose and counter-propose a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, model, state-machine

I have a model that allows user A to propose a time for an appointment to user B. If B accepts, then event is set. But if B proposes another time, then A must accept or propose another time, and so on. Until one user accept the other's counter-proposal, the appointment won't be set.

How should I model this kind of back and forth proposals and to keep track of current stage in Rails?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a state machine.

[Older SO question discussing the various gems and plugins of the time, plus some basics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349711/ruby-on-rails-state-machines)

[Newer blog post discussing the hows and whys.](http://www.shopify.com/technology/3383012-why-developers-should-be-force-fed-state-machines)

Comment: Thanks a lot, jdl. I am new to state machine, but after reading the links you provided, I can see why it is relevant. I just wonder if I abandon the goal of keeping records of all proposals, it would be an overkill to use SM in my case (just two states: pending and accepted).

Comment: The historical record keeping should be separate from the back-and-forth maintenance of the current state. Your two states (although you're probably missing some type of 'rejected' state) seem simple enough, but maybe that's a good excuse to learn about state machines with an easy use case.